# Add Image Dimensions to Cache Thumbnail

Tags: magento-1.9, image, cache, thumbnail

According to gtmetrix.com, I need to specify image dimensions on /media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/300x300/......

I know what I need to do; in that I need to add 'width="300" height="300" but I can't find where I need to add this to? I tried app/design/frontend/THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml but no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The file which contains the images for the product view is in a separate file. You will find it in catalog/product/view/media.phtm. It sounds like your wanting to resize the gallery images? If so they are towards the bottom of the file.

You can use the resize function to resize to the desired size and then set the width and size of the img element using the syntax in your question.

Hope this helps.

Josh

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't see, to do it though. It looks like it's for a thumbnail, but the bit that confuses me is it mentions /cache ?

Comment: This is just where Magento stores a cached image to help with performance. What exactly are you trying to change? Which image in particular?

Comment: There's about 10 of them but they all start with the link above - /media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/300x300/......